# Alert After jQuery Function is Finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying very hard to figure out how to get a JS alert to appear only after a previous script ([a glossary word replacement script](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zglossary/)) has finished.  Getting this javascript/jquery to run in order is giving me a headache as it either runs out of order, or the second part doesn't run at all.

Here is the code that is presently working WITHOUT the alert:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zglossary.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').glossary('listofwords.json');
    //want alert('finished') to happen after glossary word replacement is finished replacing words here
});
</script>

</head>
```

I've tried a lot of different things trying to get an alert to happen where that comment is, and either the alert happens immediately before any words are replaced by the zglossary script, an example of that would be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').glossary('listofwords.json');
    alert('finished');
});
</script>
```

Or the script will replace all the words and no alert happens at all.  An example of that would be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').glossary('listofwords.json');
}, function() {
    alert('finished');
});
</script>
```

Another example of that happening (words are replaced, but no alert happens) that I've tried would be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').glossary('listofwords.json', function() {alert('finished');} );
});
</script>
```

I really just can't figure this out.  I'd appreciate any help

Comment: is glossary a plugins!!! check if that has a callback function and use that ??

Comment: also check if the plugin gets invoked asynchronously. if not then it would anyway return only after it's finished its job.

Comment: Looking through zglossary's source, there doesn't appear to be any way to specify a completion-callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this glossary plugin before - but I downloaded the source and I see the issue is clearly because the glossary plugin does not provide any callback after the JSON data is asynchronously downloaded. Any solution that is not hacky will require a slight modification to the library itself.

[Here is a quick way you could do it](http://www.diffchecker.com/23ubtrod)

By adding this line

```
typeof options.callback == 'function' && options.callback();
```

At the end of the `success: function(data) {`

Then your code would simply be this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').glossary('listofwords.json', {callback:function() {alert('finished');}} );
});
</script>
```

Which is similar to your last example, only it puts the callback into an options JSON which is what the plugin expects.

Comment: You just helped me very much, you have no idea.  Not only for finding the solution for this, but also helping me expand my knowledgebase.  I wasn't just looking for an answer alone, but an answer that by knowing it, will help me with future problems.  Thanks again.

Comment: It probably would be better to provide the callback function as a third parameter or return a promise object you can work with but nonetheless nice and concise workaround.

Comment: @Christoph I would say that your suggestions would work, but I wouldn't recommend either for 2 reasons... 1) The API of the existing plugin already has a 2nd argument to place all optional parameters, and this callback is considered optional so it belongs in there, 2) Returning a promise object is not recommended for jQuery plugins because you expect the return object always to be a reference to the jQuery object for chaining plugins together.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's "Glossary", but you might find a solution with Deferred object supplied by jQuery [api](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Deferred helps to handle json calls, especially the *.done()* method to set a caalback when the call is finished.